# How can I turn mods on and off with Modloader without uninstalling them?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I keep several different `.jar`'s in my `.minecraft` folder for different mods.  `ModA.jar` works fine, but when opening `ModB.jar`, Modloader crashes because it's trying to load Mod A.

How can I tell it to ignore that mod (for now)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inside `.minecraft/config`, there is a file called `Modloader.cfg`.

Here's what mine looks like:

```
#ModLoader Config
#Wed Feb 15 13:42:15 EST 2012
mod_IC2=on
mod_Planes=on
mod_SpawnerGUI=on
mod_MAtmos=on
mod_TooManyItems=on
mod_BuildCraftTransport=on
mod_BuildCraftFactory=on
mod_WW2Guns=on
mod_BuildCraftBuilders=on
mod_mocreatures=off
mod_BuildCraftEnergy=on
mod_TwilightForest=on
grassFix=true
loggingLevel=FINER
mod_MineColony=on
mod_ClayMan=on
mod_BuildCraftCore=on
```

Yep, it's that simple.  Just change `on` to `off` and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Simply rename the `ModB.jar` to something like `ModB.jar.notnow`.

NB: You can rename it to `[1] ModB.jar` to have it loaded *before* `ModA.jar` which *may* fix your problems...

Answer (score 0):

I normally use MultiMC to manage my different Minecraft instances. It takes a bit more discspace, but this way it's a double click to start and no margin for errors once configured (I imagine that funny things will happen if you load one world that was actually for a different mod-set).